# Why does python time taken to multiply two n digit integers only increase when n is increased in 10s?

Tags: python, time-complexity, multiplication

I am figuring out the time taken on my computer to calculate the product of two n digit integers.

I am using this code to do so:

```
import timeit
for i in range(50):
    avg=0
    for j in range(30):
        avg+=timeit.timeit('a*b','a='+str(10**i)+';b='+str(10**i))
    print(avg/30)
```

It returns results that graph to:

[image]

Where the X axis is n and the Y axis is the time taken in seconds. As you can see, the time taken increases at about n when it is a multiple of 10, and is not constantly increasing.

I do not understand why the time taken varies like this.

Comment: Because you are adding a decimal digit to what `str()` has to do. The multiplication is insignificant compared to the radix conversion.

Comment: @user207421: No, none of the radix conversion is in the code being timed. The `str` calls are only used to construct the setup code.

Comment: @user2357112 your ideas on this tree problem:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56549158/how-to-count-the-number-of-intersections

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Python int's magnitude is [stored](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.3/Include/longintrepr.h) as a sequence of 30-bit chunks (or sometimes 15-bit chunks, but that's rarer these days). Making your numbers 9 decimal digits longer takes about 30 bits, and the time taken to multiply two numbers depends mostly on how many 30-bit chunks each number takes, so the times increase at increments of about 9 decimal digits.

Comment: So why does the amount of time taken vary with even 30 tries for average?

Comment: Since the timing is a random value, you probably want to look not only at average of it, but also to [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation). It looks highly likely that within each 9-digit range all values lie within the standard deviation range of the average, so it's just a manifestation of randomness of CPU work (e.g. other processes, context switch, etc.) and not something attributed to the algorithm being used.